# I keep editing CSS of dom elements in my javascript. Is there a good model to follow that allows no 'CSS' to be written within my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My web site changes the CSS of some DOM elements when certain events occur, but I find it icky to have CSS in both my static CSS files and in my javascript files. Is there a good model that I can stick to that allows me to change the CSS of elements in javascript while not having explicit CSS in my javascript code?

Currently I'm using calls like:

```
$domElement.css ('cssProperty', 'cssValue');
```

in my javascript code, but I don't want to do that since the CSS info should be in its own file.

What good options do I have?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: It's really hard to tell from an example this generic. What are you trying to ultimately accomplish? Maybe what you need can be done with CSS classes.

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to reduce how many times I set the CSS through javascript. I do think for most purposes the choosing of the class based on the selection is a good idea. Although I think it makes my CSS much longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to define different classes in your CSS file, then do this instead,

```
$domElement.addClass("theclassname");
```

Of course, if you're generating the `'cssValue'` part of your example dynamically, then you can't specify the CSS ahead of time, so you have no choice but to modify it directly with JavaScript as you are currently doing.

Comment: Does addClass remove the previous class that it has?

Comment: No, it just adds another class to the already existing ones. So if it had the class of "foo" and you did .addClass("bar"), it would have the classes of both "foo" and "bar". You can use .removeClass() to remove all current classes from an element before doing the .addClass(), or you can use .removeClass("foo") to just remove the class "foo", etc. if you know what classes it currently has.